# Kwalify YAML Validation - Use regexes in key names?

Tags: ruby, validation, yaml

I'm using Kwalify for schema validation. One part of the YAML document actually does want to allow for key names of a certain type in a mapping.

I see that Kwalify support regexes for the *values* in a mapping, but I see no such mention of support for using regexes in the *keys* in a mapping. Here's what I'd like to support validating:

```
test-element:
  sub-element-1: test
  sub-element-2:
    element-with-pattern-1: test1
    element-with-pattern-2: test2
```

So I don't know what some key names will exactly be in advance (shown here with the fake names "element-with-pattern-*", but I do know that they should correspond to a pattern defined by a regex.

Is this possible to validate using Kwalify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible given the current state of the code.

I'm actually in a similar situation, which I found out (the hard way) does not work well for validation in the Kwalify context.  I've begun migrating away from flexible key names into a paradigm where I can specifically define the schema.

For example, I migrated this:

```
parent_key:
  random_key1: url1
  random_key2: url2
```

To:

```
parent_key:
  - name: random_key1
    url: url1 
  - name: random_key2
    url: url2
```

With the latter syntax, you can validate like this:

```
"parent_key":
  type: seq
  sequence:
    - type: map
      mapping:
        "name":
          type: str
          required: yes
        "url":
          type: str
          required: yes
```

Within that context, you can add a `pattern` regex validators to either `name` or `url` that should allow you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5):

To check this:

```
parent_key:
  random_key1: url1
  random_key2: url2
```

you should use "Default of Mapping", here is schema example:

```
type: map
mapping:
  "parent_key":
    type: map
    mapping:
      "=":
        type: str
```

http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwalify/ruby/users-guide.02.html#tips-default